# Tab key not working over Remote Desktop

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

I am using Debian on a VPS. I am connecting to it from Remote desktop on my Windows machine.

if I use PuTTY to connect, I can use the Tab-key just fine, files in the terminal auto complete.

If I use remote desktop to connect, the Tab key does not work in mousepad, gedit, or the terminal. I can use the Tab-key w/ the Alt-key to switch between open windows so I know Debian keyboard layout is ok (I hope)...

I am logged in as Root ( I don't want to have permissions blocking me and I want this change for all users). I have also tried this with another user too.

**/etc/bash.bashrc**

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
   elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

**/etc/profile**

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
  . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

**~/.bashrc**

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Run the program `xev` from a terminal and press Tab. What does it show? (It should result in two paragraphs, one beginning with `KeyPress event` and one beginning with `KeyRelease event`.)

Comment: I get the following:

Comment: FocusOut event, serial 31, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001, mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

Comment: KeymapNotify event, serial 31, synthetic NO, window 0x0, keys: 126 0  0  0 ... < a lot of zeros> ...

Comment: In the terminal, I noticed that if I hold the CTRL button down and hit tab, the auto-complete function behaves as expected... However, when typing within gedit, for example, if I hit TAB key, nothing happens still. If I hold CTRL and TAB, nothing happens, ALT & TAB toggles between open windows and SHIFT & TAB does nothing still :/ .... any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your posts to add the `xev` output, comments are unreadable for this. But we don't need the `FocusOut` and `KeymapNotify` events, those are related to the focusing of the xev window itself. Only the events when you press the Tab key. If no event is generated at that time, that's information too.